# Qt debugger stuck when running on Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, qt, lldb

I updated my Xcode yesterday. Now I cannot debug code in Qt, as it is always stuck "running". I'm using LLDB on Mac OS X 10.10.5 and Xcode 7.0.

Comment: Are you using it from Xcode or from Qt Creator? If it doesn't work from Xcode, file a bug with Apple - there's nothing for you to "fix", most likely. It's supposed to work.

Comment: @KubaOber I'm using it from Qt Creator. But I think the LLDB is related to Xcode, so I rollback it to Xcode 6.4. And everything went back to normal.

Comment: There used to be a bug that required a manual tickling of the debugger. In Qt Creator, open the debugger console, and press enter to try to get it moving ahead. Also make sure you're using Xcode 3.5.