# Qt multithreaded project - debugger freezes

Tags: c++, macos, qt, lldb

Following youtube tutorial I've wrote a pretty basic multithreaded app.

The problem with it, is that I cannot debug it. It looks like the program does not even enter main function because It does not stop on breakpoint at the very beginning of main function. If I press pause to see where the program currently is, the debugger freezes on message "Attempting to interrupt".

Interesting thing is that other projects that are not using threading work just fine with debugger. This multithreaded project works fine on Windows platform.

I am using QT Creator 3.4.2 that is basing on Qt 5.5.0(Clang 6.0, 64 bit). It was built on Jun 29 2015. I have the latest updates of OS X and Xcode.

Comment: doesnt look that basic. is it a release build? Otherwise it make no sense not to hit breakpoint into main.

Comment: It is a debug build. It is basic, it has two classes, one inherits from QTcpServer and the second from QRunnable. I think it does not have more that 50-60 lines of code. It is just a test project

Comment: When the debugger fails to hit a breakpoint, it's often the case that the target being debugged does not match the code in Qt Creator.

Comment: which means you should force qmake && make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution thanks to
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642832/qt-debugger-stuck-when-running-on-mac).

To solve this kind of problem I had to switch back from Xcode 7.0.1 to 6.4.